# What are best practices for sub-domain-based accounts in Django?

Tags: django

The use case is pretty straight forward SaaS:

- each account gets a sub-domain
- each account has multiple users, with multiple roles

Most of my searches turn up apps/packages from 2007-2009, and I am not sure that what I find is still relevant.

Comment: Multiple domains is pretty easily handled with the sites framework. Distinct users per domain, however, is not supported by the auth framework (`User` is not tied to `Site` in anyway). You might be able to pull something off with user profiles and a bit of admin hacking, though.

Answer (score 1):

For me this simple snippet is enought to get account name from subdomain: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1119/, there is also a newer middleware: https://github.com/tkaemming/django-subdomains. In django database you could use this domain name as a prefix for username and keep all of them in django standard auth_user table (just add/cut this prefix during authentication or when you want to dispaly this name).
What problems do you have with these snippets? 
The only problem from my point of view is automatic setup of subdomains, but it depends on your hosting, does it has these API or not.